# Input type file event after select and open a file

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have this HTML code:

```
<input type="file" id="mysignature_upload" onChange="readURL();"/>
```

Javascript code:

```
function readURL(){
  alert("Hello");
}
```

The problem with this code is, the function readURL only gets called when you select a different file, but if you select the same file over and over again, readURL cannot be executed. I want to know if there's an event that fires when you select and open a file even if the file selected is the same with the previous file selected.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vhevhangvhakhikhang/78zcp5u7/

Comment: when you can select same file again and again then it can not change the file so you can use click event and get this.value

Comment: @priya786 --> onclick would be an answer if and only if it will wait for the user to select and open a file. Unfortunately it is not

Comment: I'm not sure if it satisfies your requirements, but you can delete the last value each time the user press the button (with onclick event) and then when he choose a file the onchange will work.

Comment: simply clear the value onchange(), and change() will fire each selection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function({
      $("#mysignature_upload").click(function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
         $(this).val("");
      });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

I hope its satisfies your requirements: [fiddle exapmle](http://jsfiddle.net/8d2qdcey/1/)

```
   <input type="file" id="mysignature_upload"/>

    $("#mysignature_upload").click(function (event) {
         $("#mysignature_upload").val("");
    });

    $("#mysignature_upload").on('change',function (event) {
        alert("selected file: " + $("#mysignature_upload").val());
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

As the name suggests, `onchange` is triggered only if the value of the field is changed. If you need to do something every time the user selects a file, probably, you could reset the field's value on `click` event.

```
$("#mysignature_upload").click(function() {
  // clear the value
  $(this).val("");
 }
}
```

Now `onchange` will get triggered every time.

Comment: @ItayB - yeah right, onclick would be an answer if and only if it will wait for the user to select and open a file. Unfortunately it is not.

Answer (score 0):

When selecting large files, there is a noticeable delay between clicking Open in the file dialog and the value of the (type file) input updating.  While I use the following two events for showing and hiding a 'please wait' dialog, you could 'do other stuff' in these events as well:

```
    // Fires upon click of the file input ('Choose File' button)
    $('#selectedFile').on('click', function (event) {
        // Shows before file selection dialog and remains behind
        // the file selection dialog (which has a higher z-order)
        ShowPleaseWait();
    });

    // Fires the moment that the file input value itself is updated.
    // NOTE: This is NOT when the Open button is clicked ... this
    // is when the value of the file input actually updates (there is
    // a delay after clicking Open for a large file until the value
    // of the input actually, finally, updates...)
    $('#selectedFile').on('change', function (event) {
        HidePleaseWait();
    });
```